# Raspberry pi 4 1 short 1 long blinks

Tags: boot, act

I have a Raspberry pi 4 model B, have been using it for more than a year. A few days ago it started having problems. After 10/20 seconds from startup it gives an error pattern that looks like 1 short and 1 long blinks on the ACT led.

I haven't found a reference for that error and don't have an adapter for the display. I've tried cloning the microsd and a fresh raspbian install but the problem persists.

Here's a video of the pattern: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tpOHR6Y9cdXKcjGSOp51kMSntu-0FG0K/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is connected to your GPIO pins? I suggest you remove those, I see bare wire that could short out pins. I assume by 'raspbian' you mean the latest Raspberry Pi OS flashed using Pi Imager?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with my Zero 2, and it ended up being a bad USB power cable. If you're still having this issue, try a different cable to see if that helps.